# Can we get approval process fields in Visualforce email template?

Tags: email-template, approval-process, visualforce-template

Can we get approval process fields in Notification (Visualforce)template?

if yes, how to get the current approver?

I need to change the email verbiage based on the approver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Winter 14 release notes:

```
Approval Comment Merge Fields are Available in All Approvals-Related Email Alerts
The {!ApprovalRequest.Comments} merge field can be used in any approvals-related email alert.

Available in: Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer Editions

Previously, all approval merge fields named {!ApprovalRequest.field_name} returned
values only when used in an approval assignment email template. 

When used in templates for other email alert actions—in workflow rules or approval processes—
the approval merge fields returned null. 

Now, for example, if a request is rejected at any approval step, 
you can include the approver’s rejection comment in an email alert to the submitter.

Note: The {!ApprovalRequest.Comments} merge field returns only the most recently
entered comment in emails for an approval step that requires unanimous approval from
multiple approvers.
```

So, it depends on both which merge field you are using and whether you are using the merge field in a template used during approval assignment or in some approval action email alert

Comment: These merge fields do not work in a visualforce email template.